# Opentk LookAt() and 'eye' argument rotating

Tags: c#, 3d, vector, opentk

I'm trying to create rotating camera, which looks down by 45 deegre like this:
[image: rotating example]

However my code for rotating eye vector is not working properly and I achieve vertical rotation, when it should be horizontal. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Camera
{
    private Vector3 target;
    private Vector3 origin;
    private float rotation;
    public Matrix4 ModelViewMatrix;

    public Camera(Vector3 target)
    {
        this.target = target;
        origin = target + new Vector3(5);
        SetMatrix();
    }

    public void Move(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        Move(new Vector3(x, y, z));
    }

    public void Move(Vector3 translation)
    {
        target += translation;
        origin += translation;
        SetMatrix();
    }

    public void Rotate(float deegres)
    {
        rotation += MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(deegres);
        SetMatrix();
    }

    public void Zoom(float zoom)
    {
        origin += new Vector3(zoom);
        SetMatrix();
    }

    private void SetMatrix()
    {
        var rotationMatrix = Matrix4.CreateFromAxisAngle(target, rotation); // rotation around target
        var eye = Vector4.Transform(new Vector4(origin, 1), rotationMatrix);
        ModelViewMatrix = Matrix4.LookAt(eye.Xyz, target, Vector3.UnitY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing the target vector in for the rotation axes? Also, wouldn't you want to input ( target - origin ) into Vector4.Transform instead of just origin? You want to rotate about the target, which has nothing to do with LookAt.

Comment: @Ben you should expand your comment into an answer, it seems right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I see two problems here:

```
var rotationMatrix = Matrix4.CreateFromAxisAngle(target, rotation);
```

This line is passing the target vector into the method to create a rotation. That's probably not right. If you want to rotate about the axis shown in your picture, you'd want to pass it the global up vector, like you do in your LookAt line.

The second problem is:

```
var eye = Vector4.Transform(new Vector4(origin, 1), rotationMatrix);
```

This will rotate the origin( camera position ) vector about the origin( 0, 0, 0 ). This isn't what you want either. If you want to rotate about the target, you write:

```
var eye = Vector4.Transform( new Vector4( ( orgin - target ), 1 ), rotationMatrix ) + target;
```

This way we're rotation the vector from the target to the origin( camera position ) about ( 0, 0, 0 ). This will give us our rotated vector relative to the target, then we simply add the target vector to get back to where we were.

Comment: Thank you for explaining me this. I trough Matrix4.CreateFromAxisAngle() is to crate "around point" rotation but I understand now how vector rotation works so I have also updated my translation method to work properly :)

Comment: Sorry to resurrect an old question, but for the rest of us in the second solution can you tell us how a Vector4 might easily be used in the `eye` definition.. It's essentially adding a Vector4 and a Vector3 together.

Comment: @cossacksman Yeah, you'd need to create a new vector to do this addition. It'll be new Vector4( target.X, target.Y, target.Z, 0.0f ); Then they can be added together.